# What is Docky.exe in /usr/lib/docky/plugins?

Tags: mono, docky

## Why there is a Windows version of Docky found inside my Ubuntu 12.04?

[image]

I'm seeing this in my process list : `mono /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe`

Is this safe?
Can I have the Linux native Docky(Linux Binary)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *is* the Linux native version of Docky.

`.dll` and `.exe` files are typical for applications developed in [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page).

As you can see from the [`docky` package file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/docky/filelist), no other binaries are included. Docky wouldn't work if only Windows binaries were included. Also, your statement about you see that process running, indicates the same.

And yes, it's safe. It's the nature of Mono-developed applications.